# Law of iterated expectation - $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] \mid Z ] = \mathbb{E}[X]$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am stuck doing this problem:

$X,Y,Z$ be random variables, then: $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] \mid  Z ] = \mathbb{E}[X]$$

Surely this is from LIE and conditioning, but I can't seem to set it up correctly for it to work out nicely, can anyone point me in the right direction, or correct my error below?

Below is the way I was attacking this, but quickly got stuck and it's making me think I simply didn't set up my summation correctly. The expectation inside the conditional is really throwing me for a loop.

My take (likely incorrect):
\begin{align} \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]\mid Z] &= \sum_zP(Z=z) (\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y])\\
&=\sum_zP(Z=z)\sum_x xP(X=x\mid Y=y)\\ &= \sum_zP(Z=z)\sum_x x \frac{P(X=x, Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}\end{align}

and I don't see where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Thank you to everyone who commented and pointed out this is generally false. After asking my professor the question should really be

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] \mid  Z ]] = \mathbb{E}[X]$$

I haven't done the proof yet, but I assume this follows cleanly from LIE.

Comment: It is not true generally.  For example, $X=Y=Z$ a Bernoulli(p), $0<p<1$.

Comment: No chance for such thing to hold for arbitrary r.v. 's. Where did you find this?

Comment: This is false in general (e.g. choose $X=Y=Z$ for a trivial counterexample).  Do you have any independence assumptions?

Comment: I was weary of this as well, as I've seen tons of proofs of E[E[X|Y]|Z] = E[X,Z], but those didn't really help me here, and I wasn't confident enough to question the problem.

Comment: You might be "weary" of it as well, but I would guess you mean "wary"? (Even if it's merely a typo, I still appreciated it as a play on words)

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes lol, oops. @ Kavi This question was a challenge from my professor as an optional exercise after we did the proof for LIE, he very well may have forgotten to state they are independent, in which case I suspect I would be able to do this relatively easily once I figure out how to set up my summation. I also just emailed him to confirm.

Comment: I would have thought $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] \mid  Z ]$ would in general be a function of $Z$ and possibly of $Y$ while $\mathbb{E}[X]$ would be a number

Comment: In the corrected question, I guess you could first apply LIE to the random variable $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ to obtain $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] \mid  Z ]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]]$, and then again to $X$ to obtain $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]] = \mathbb{E}[X]$

Comment: @hgmath this is what I was likely going to do, but it seemed almost too trivial haha. Wish the problem was more worthy of a post with such discussion.

Comment: BTW: A somewhat important extension on the original question is whether it is necessarily true when $X,Z$ are independent.  The answer is no, the details of which become important when composing filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[We are presuming $X,Y,Z$ are discrete random variables.]

Since $\Bbb E(X\mid Y)$ is a function of random variable $Y$, then we have:

$\qquad\begin{align}\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X\mid Y)\mid Z)&=\left[\sum_y\mathsf E(X\mid Y\,{=}\,y)\,\mathsf P(Y\,{=}\,y\mid Z\,{=}\,z)\right]_{z=Z} \\ &=\left[\sum\limits_y\left(\sum\limits_x x\,\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,x\mid Y\,{=}\,y)\right)\mathsf P(Y\,{=}\,y\mid Z\,{=}\,z)\right]_{z=Z}\\ &=\left[\sum\limits_{x} x\sum\limits_{y}\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,x\mid Y\,{=}\,y)\,\mathsf P(Y\,{=}\,y\mid Z\,{=}\,z)\right]_{z=Z}\end{align}$

Thus it shall not generally be so that $\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X\mid Y)\mid Z)=\Bbb E(X)$ unless, for example, $Y$ is independent of $Z$.

---

**Update**

The above expectation is a function of $Z$. The OP has updated the question to be about the expectation of this.  So let us do that, distribute the series and apply the law of total probability...

$\qquad\begin{align}\Bbb E(\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X\mid Y)\mid Z))&=\sum\limits_z\sum\limits_{x} x\sum\limits_{y}\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,x\mid Y\,{=}\,y)\,\mathsf P(Y\,{=}\,y\mid Z\,{=}\,z)\,\mathsf P(Z\,{=}\,z)\\&=\sum\limits_{x} x\sum\limits_{y}\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,x\mid Y\,{=}\,y)\sum\limits_z\mathsf P(Y\,{=}\,y\mid Z\,{=}\,z)\,\mathsf P(Z\,{=}\,z)\\&=\sum\limits_{x} x\sum\limits_{y}\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,x\mid Y\,{=}\,y)\,\mathsf P(Y\,{=}\,y)\\&=\sum\limits_x x\,\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,x)\\&=\Bbb E(X)\end{align}$

Comment: I've marked this as the answer since it disproves my original post, but I've edited my post to correct the question.

Comment: @Ralph.  I've added an update, and indeed the triple expectation does easily prove to be the expectation of $X$.  (As long as the random variables are well behaved.)